# Smoothing Accelerometer Values

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, lowpass-filter

I am creating an android phonegap application that uses the accelerometer to detect imperfections on the road.  However, when I am using the raw accelerometer values (x, y, and z) they vary too much from one try to another.  I tried taking the same imperfection using the same device, same vehicle and position, however the values given by the accelerometer are completely different.  I am getting the accelerometer value every .25 of a second so every second I would get 4 values of x, y and z.

Can anyone tell me how I would be able to smooth the values in order to get a smoother and more reliable value?  I will need to use these values to do further processing on them, so the accuracy of the x, y and z values is vital.   Is there any formula that can be applied to the values to get a smoother output?

UPDATED:
Adding a snippet of my code:

```
function acc() {
var accOpt = { frequency: 1000 };  
previousReading = {
    x   :   null,
    y   :   null,
    z   :   null,
    lr  :   null,
    fb  :   null            
  }; 
watchID = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(win, fail, accOpt);    
}

function win (acceleration) {

var tiltLR = 0;
var tiltFB = 0;

var facingUp = -1;
if (acceleration.z > 0) {
  facingUp = +1;
}

tiltLR = Math.round(((acceleration.x) / 9.81) * -90);
tiltFB = Math.round(((acceleration.y + 9.81) / 9.81) * 90 * facingUp);



  var changes = {};

  if (previousReading.x !== null) {
      changes.x = Math.abs(previousReading.x-acceleration.x);
      changes.y = Math.abs(previousReading.y-acceleration.y);
      changes.z = Math.abs(previousReading.z-acceleration.z);
      changes.lr = Math.abs(previousReading.lr-tiltLR);
      changes.fb = Math.abs(previousReading.fb-tiltFB);
  }

  previousReading = {
      x: acceleration.x,
      y: acceleration.y,
      z: acceleration.z,
      lr: tiltLR,
      fb: tiltFB
  };


console.log('previousReading x: ' + previousReading.x + ' previousReading y: ' + previousReading.y + ' previousReading z: ' + previousReading.z+ ' previousReading lr: ' + tiltLR + ' previousReading fb: ' + tiltFB);

console.log('changes x: ' + changes.x  + ' changes y: ' + changes.y + ' changes z: ' + changes.z + ' changes lr: ' + changes.lr + ' changes fb: ' + changes.fb);

console.log(acceleration.x + ' ' + acceleration.y + ' ' + acceleration.z);

 }
```

Filters:
I have come across this code to smooth a bit the x, y and z values.  If I apply this to the current x,y,z value and then compare them with the previous ones (which are also filtered out), would this work in my case?

```
 #define kFilteringFactor 0.1

 // Use a basic low-pass filter to keep only the gravity component of each axis.
 grav_accelX = (acceleration.x * kFilteringFactor) + ( grav_accelX * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));
 grav_accelY = (acceleration.y * kFilteringFactor) + ( grav_accelY * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));
 grav_accelZ = (acceleration.z * kFilteringFactor) + ( grav_accelZ * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));

 // Subtract the low-pass value from the current value to get a simplified high-pass filter
 instant_accelX = acceleration.x - ( (acceleration.x * kFilteringFactor) + (instant_accelX * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor)) );
 instant_accelY = acceleration.y - ( (acceleration.y * kFilteringFactor) + (instant_accelY * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor)) );
 instant_accelZ = acceleration.z - ( (acceleration.z * kFilteringFactor) + (instant_accelZ * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor)) );
```

Comment: What kind of imperfections are we talking about here?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen potholes, speedbumps etc

Comment: what is the use of tiltLR and tiltFB?